# Reset Timer Service in Share Point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices, timer-service

The SharePoint **timer service** unexpectedly stopped, now I need to **reset** it to default state because there is a change in login account and password. 
This is the reason that might be causing this issue.

How can I reset the timer service in this case?

Comment: couple of things to check: make sure you have the config cache folder exist? how many server in the farm? did you update the password in sharepoint central admin or u change it from services

Comment: I change password from my service..how can I changed from central admin? @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Comment: from central admin > security > configured managed account...over here update the farm admin account password.

Comment: config cache folder is exist but it is different ID, then I **create folder** from copy Id from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\ConfigDB  ID, and another thing I already **update password** through **powershell command** "stsadm -o updatefarmcredentials -userlogin domain\account -password password " this command but problem remain same @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check may be [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff805056.aspx) was happen for

I set my farm account and service account same, that is not suggested

Answer (score 3):

Once you have changed the credentials, just restart the timer service. This will reset the credentials and apply the new ones.

Restating the service will not create any problems.

Comment: while I restart service, it not started

Comment: Please let me know what error does it throw so that I can help you.

Comment: When I started service, in event log error is "timer service stop unexpectedly"



Event ID:      7031
Event ID:      7024



in every two minute



error description:
Description:
The SharePoint 2010 Timer service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 5969 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 30000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Answer (score 3):

You can go through the Url :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704549.aspx

or you can apply this:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.Instances | foreach { $_.Stop(); $_.Start(); }
```

Comment: It start successfully but, after 2 min. again service stopped unexpectedly
and in event viewer throw error mention in above commented answer by me,  is there any service crash issue, and how to solve it..? @AsadRefai

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try clearing the configuration cache.

The steps for doing this are posted on a few places on the web, here's a link to one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

The steps are formatted and it'll take too long to copy and paste and reformat here, but essentially -

- Stop the timer service
- Go to `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\*GUID*`
- Back up `Cache.ini`
- Delete all the `.xml` files
- Open `Cache.ini`
- Replace the contents with the number `1`
- Save the file
- Start the timer service.

Comment: there is no cache.ini file in config folder @james-love

Comment: I also create folder in %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\*GUID* , for that copy Id from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\Secure\ConfigDB ID , but problem remain same @robert-lindgren